# How can I limit the length of content in the webview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments

Let's say that I have a WebView:

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
{
  Log.d(TAG, "Finished: " + url);
  super.onPageFinished(view, url);

  Log.d(TAG, "webView.getContentHeight(): " + webView.getContentHeight());
  Log.d(TAG, "webView.getHeight(): " + webView.getHeight());
  Log.d(TAG, "view.getContentHeight(): " + view.getContentHeight());
}
```

where it returns:

webView.getContentHeight(): 4059
  webView.getHeight(): 1746

Now, I'd like to chop off  bottom 500 pixels of the web contents (e.g. 4059 px --> become 3559 px) while still maintaining it's viewable webview height 1746.

Could anyone give me an idea?  I'd sincerely appreciate that!

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to accomplish - changing the "contentHeight" requires changing the content and re-loading the page.

So I assume you are trying to prevent the content from being seen, in which case you can override `scrollTo` and prevent the scroll from going past a specific margin of content like so:

```
 int myMargin = 500;
```

Then:

```
 @Override
 public void scrollTo(int x, int y){
      int maxScroll = webView.getContentHeight() - myMargin;
      if (y > maxScroll) {
           super.scrollTo(x, maxScroll);
      } else {
           super.scrollTo(x,y);
      }
 }
```

Comment: So far I had no effect by placing "maxScroll = webView.getContentHeight() - myMargin" in the onCreatView in a fragment.  Where would you advice to place this statement?

Comment: You may need to get the content height inside `scrollTo` but I had assumed that you already knew your content before the user could scroll. I edited my answer if you have dynamic content.